# Unknown source of voltage through a CMOS switching IC

Tags: switches, cmos, switching

I am using a CD4066 IC in the below configuration. The 5V is coming through a LDO. The switches in the CD4066 are being thrown high and low through Arduino digital pins 2,3,4 and 5. Surprisingly I am able to read voltage on the Arduino pin A0 even when the LDO is not powered. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the supply to 4066 is turned off, you cannot have any voltages on 4066 IO pins for any reason.

If you do, such as even one Arduino pin high, the 4066 is powered through that IO pin and the inbuilt protection diodes.